# Best way to have a ListView which I will re-use on a click

Tags: android

I am about to implement a listview which is going to be somewhat complex...

The Listview will go something like this to the user using it...

Main ListView shows > Click Popular Places > Choose Category (health + medical) > Narrow down choice (choose pharmacy) > Create a completely new listview which will then use the places API to get some data to fill in the listview...

All of this has to be done on one fragment (for easy for the user, plus it should be quicker) What is the best way of doing this? When they click "health + medical" the next listview should only show "pharmacy" + other medical types in the places API... What is the best way of doing things?

Sorry if this is a bit hard to understand, I can try and explain it better if required. Hope this question belongs here too! I know its a bit "general" but could do with some guidance...

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter class? You can set a variable `String category="health + medical"` and then when you want to narrow them down, remove all listing whose category != health + medical

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter class? You can set a variable `String category="health + medical"` and then when you want to narrow them down, remove all listing whose category != health + medical

Comment: you can store all of your lists' items as arrays in String.xml and load it to ListView based on the user's choice